# Server Side Pagination

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, pagination, server-side

I am loading data into my `DataGrid` via the `ItemsSource` property. I have a `DataPager` as well for pagination. The `Grid` is populated by calling a WCF service which returns a `List`.

```
public void webService_GetProductsCompleted(object sender, GetServiceReference.GetProductsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   PagedCollectionView pagingCollection = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result);
   pgrProductGrids.Source = pagingCollection;
   grdProductGrid.ItemsSource = pagingCollection;
}
```

**Now** there is a new requiremement that I want to load data with `server side pagination`. I'm a newbie learning `Silverlight` and for me the concept of `server side paging` is completely new too. So I came here to know what's required for `server side pagination`. Any good `examples`, `tutorials`,`step-by-step guidelines` that can give me a direction? I have to complete this task in a limited time. Please guide seniors

Comment: Are you unable to find any tutorials on google.com? Or is "not making any work" better for you?

Comment: I did but everything seems very confusing so I came here if any one can give a general guideline of the steps involved so I know what to particularly search for on the internet. Currently I have no clue. Also most of the examples use `WCF RIA Services`, I want to know how can I get it working without `RIA`

Answer (score 0):

I typically use 1 of these 2 options:

1: If your data is sorted/paged by a field that has a unique value in it, let the database do the heavy lifting by utilizing the `TOP` feature and an `ORDER BY`. This way the smallest amount of data is returned from the server to the page. In the following example, MyTable has a field "NAME" that is unique and is how I want the data sorted. I am getting 10 records per page.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM MyTable Where Name> [The last name in the previous 10 results] ORDER BY Name
```

You could use this for multiple fields if you wanted to use a windowing function like ROW_NUMBER() (I don't know what database you are using, this assumes SQL Server)

2: If this is not the case, then it gets ugly. You need to get all the data and get all the records between [The last page * Number per page] and the number of records per page in some iterative code. (Ugly, slow, lots of memory, not possible on large data sets.)